# Filter a data frame according to a list for "AT LEAST ONE" cooccurrence

Tags: r, filter, subset

I am starting with a data frame and list like those that follow.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Benjamin", "Benjamin", "Benjamin", "Benjamin", "Benjamin", "Gary", "Gary", "Gary", "Gary", "Gary", "Maria", "Maria", "Maria", "Maria", "Maria", "Maria"),

                 sport = c("Lacrosse", "Billiards", "Football (US)", "Basketball", "Baseball", "Football (International)", "Baseball", "Golf", "Volleyball", "Archery", "Chess", "Tennis", "Gymnastics", "Parkour", "Dodgeball", "Paintball"))

 

test <- c("Billiards", "Tennis", "Paintball")
```

I am trying to figure out how to filter the `df` data frame by the values in the `test` list, such that it would only return Benjamin and Maria, as only those two individuals have an observation that includes a sport in the `test` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the subset command:

```
df_sub <- subset(df, sport %in% test)
```

And if you just want the two names you can further use:

`unique(df_sub$name)`